# Python: Convert data file format to string

Tags: python, string, file, character-encoding

I have a file that has the following output when `file` command is run:

```
#file test.bin
#test.bin : data

#file -i test.bin
#test.bin: application/octet-stream; charset=binary
```

I want to read the contents of this file and forward to a python library that accepts this read-data as a string.

```
        file = open("test.bin", "rb")
        readBytes = file.read()            # python type : <class 'bytes'>
        
        output = test.process(readBytes)   # process expects a string
```

I have tried `str(readBytes)`, however that did not work. I see that there are also unprintable strings in the file `test.bin`, as the output of `strings test.bin` produces far lesser output than the actual bytes present in the file.

Is there a way to convert the bytes read into strings? Or am I trying to achieve something that makes no sense at all?

Comment: Just don't read it as bytes.
```file = open("test.bin", "r")```

Comment: @DavidMeu : I have tried this before, and it gives me the following error. `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x88 in position 18: invalid start byte`. The file being read is a encrypted key-material. I want to read the file data and forward it to a python library.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean by?

```
output = test.process(readBytes.decode('latin1'))
```

Comment: It gives the same error as mentioned in the comment above :  `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x88 in position 18: invalid start byte`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Bitstring. It's good package for reading bits.

```
# import module
from bitstring import ConstBitStream

# read file
x = ConstBitStream(filename='file.bin')

# read 5 bits
output = x.read(5)

# convert to unsigned int
int_val = output.uint
```

Comment: This works, but I observe the following :  The size of the file obtained using `os.path.getsize("test.bin")`= 3581 bytes . The read bytes after performing the above steps you mentioned = 8623.  `output = x.read(3581*8)`. Is this expected behavior?

Comment: If you have initialized a bitstring from a 1 GB file object and ask for its binary string representation then that string will be around 8 GB in size. This is expected behavior from the program. The properties can potentially be very expensive in terms of both computation and memory requirements so you must be aware of what you are doing in memory.

Comment: what i meant was, `len(str(output.uint)) = 8623`. I don't understand why the string length is not `3581*8`.